# Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group - React Native after installing firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I've been facing the following issue since I installed firebase dependencies from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/app as specified for React Native. Since then the Xcode console prints out the following error:

"ld: library not found for -lBVLinearGradient clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

That lib from Linear Gradient was causing no issue at all since the install of firebase and proper links following the documentation. Now it seems to be affecting other dependencies as well.

I've already re-created the iOS folder, ran pod install and the error persists. After doing that process, I had to link the project using react-native link to load the fonts I was using and the error came back again.

I am using the following version of Xcode: "Version 10.3 (10G8)", and the firebase dependencies inside pods folder are: "Firebase", "FirebaseCore" and "FirebaseCoreDiagnostics".

Note: inside pods folder there is no "LinearGradient" pod at all.

Comment: does this solution work for you? https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/498

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Firebase require at least Xcode 11 - and very soon, will likely require Xcode 12.